# Como recortar HTML de site com VBA?

Tags: html, microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, web-scraping

Estou tentando fazer o webscraping de um dado de um site para o excel por meio do VBA.

Consigo, no código que estou desenvolvendo, acessar o site, mas até agora não entendi bem como este dado está inserido no código... não é por uma tabela, apesar de parecer uma:

```
# o site

https://dwcontent.affino.com/AcuCustom/Sitename/DAM/019/WCI-Table_2021-12-09.svg
```

A tabela na qual estou interessado (o dado é o 9,262, Logo abixo do índice 9-Dec-21)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#Dei uma olhada no código HTML e esse é o trecho relativo ao elemento que tenho 
interesse (9,262), mas não sei se isso seria um id, uma tag... enfim, nao sei como se nomeia isso em HTML.

"<tspan xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="tspan890" y="0" x="0 5.8713598 11.74272 14.63616 20.507521 26.37888">$9,262</tspan>"
```

Meu código, hoje, está assim:

```
Sub ImportSDrewry()


Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False

ie.navigate "https://dwcontent.affino.com/AcuCustom/Sitename/DAM/019/WCI-Table_2021-12-09.svg"



Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE


DoEvents

Loop


Set html = ie.document

Cells(1, 1) = html.DocumentElement.innerHTML

MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML

Dim QuestionList As IHTMLElement

Set QuestionList = html.getElementById("tspan890")

Cells(2, 1) = QuestionList



End Sub
```

Como de se esperar, não está retornando o valor de interesse. A resposta é:

```
[object SVGTSpanElement]
```

Minha primeira dúvida é: em que tipo de elemento (tag,Id etc) a parte que eu quero está inserida?
Há algum  meio alternativo paa executar esse web scraping?

Comment: Já tentou ```QuestionList.innerText```?

Comment: A melhor forma é utilizar a biblioteca do Selenium no VBA, dessa forma você consegue implementar o getElementById corretamente.